# How to minus the padding width from 100% width?

Tags: css

When I set the padding size for input field it automatically changed the size. It becomes bigger.

```
.container{
    width: 150px;
}

.item label{    
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;    
}

.from-item{
    width: 100%;
}

input[type="text"]{ 
    width: 100%;    
    padding: 5px;   
}
```

[JSFfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aq8mP/)

Comment: what exactly you want to have? I mean what problem are you facing?

Answer (score 1):

You should think about putting this in your CSS:

```
 * { box-sizing: border-box }
```

This alters the box model such that padding will not add to the size that an element occupies on the screen. It is, to my mind and the mind of many others, a much better model to work with:

http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

General info on the box model: http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `box-sizing:border-box` to solve your problem, but it is a css3 property. Thus incompatible with old browsers.

Another way to achive this is put a wrapper div around input & give padding to it.

```
<div class="ibox"><input type="text" class="from-item"></div>

.ibox{
    padding: 5px;   
}

input[type="text"]{ 
    width: 100%;    
}
```

Here is Demo link http://jsfiddle.net/aq8mP/1/